# Positioning Asterisk Adjacent to Hint Text in Flutter TextField

Tags: flutter, colors, textfield, hint

I've developed a custom input widget in Flutter to streamline the process of adding input fields in registration forms. This widget offers a range of customizable parameters, allowing for flexible configuration to suit various form requirements.

However, I've encountered an issue with the positioning of an asterisk (*) within the input field. The intention is for the asterisk to appear immediately after the text input, typically indicating that the field is required. However, upon implementation, the asterisk consistently appears at the rightmost part of the input field, rather than adjacent to the text input as desired.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

enum InputRestriction {
  text,
  number,
  textAndNumber,
}

Widget Input({
  double borderRadius = 16,
  double width = double.infinity,
  double height = 60,
  double left = 0,
  double right = 0,
  double top = 0,
  double bottom = 0,
  String hint = "",
  double fontSize = 16,
  bool prefixIconShow = false,
  bool suffixIconShow = false,
  IconData prefixIconName = Icons.person,
  IconData suffixIconName = Icons.lock,
  TextInputType textInputType = TextInputType.text,
  Color color = AppColors.black,
  required TextEditingController controller,
  bool password = false,
  Color containerBackgroundColor = AppColors.white,
  Color textFieldBackgroundColor = AppColors.white,
  double contentPaddingLeft = 0,
  double contentPaddingRight = 0,
  TextAlign textalign = TextAlign.left,
  RichText? suffix,
  List<String>? autofillHints,
  int maxLines = 1,
  TextOverflow overflow = TextOverflow.clip,
  required InputRestriction inputRestriction,
}) {
  TextInputType getTextInputType() {
    switch (inputRestriction) {
      case InputRestriction.text:
        return TextInputType.text;
      case InputRestriction.number:
        return TextInputType.number;
      case InputRestriction.textAndNumber:
        return TextInputType.text;
      default:
        return TextInputType.text;
    }
  }

  return Visibility(
    visible: true,
    child: Container(
      width: width,
      height: height,
      padding:
          EdgeInsets.only(left: left, right: right, top: top, bottom: bottom),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(borderRadius)),
        color: containerBackgroundColor,
      ),
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(borderRadius)),
          color: textFieldBackgroundColor,
        ),
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
          children: [
            TextField(
              textAlign: textalign,
              keyboardType: getTextInputType(),
              controller: controller,
              obscureText: password,
              cursorColor: color,
              maxLines: maxLines,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: fontSize,
                fontFamily: "Poppins",
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                color: AppColors.black,
              ),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                hintText: hint,
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: contentPaddingLeft,
                  right: contentPaddingRight,
                ),
                suffixIcon: suffixIconShow
                    ? Icon(
                        suffixIconName,
                        color: color,
                      )
                    : null,
              ),
              autofillHints: autofillHints,
            ),
            Visibility(
              visible: suffix != null,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                child: suffix ?? Container(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

I want
[the asterisk to appear immediately after the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrlKe.png). But when I use it, the asterisk appears at the rightmost part of the input.

this is how I call it

```
Expanded(
      child: Input(
    inputRestriction: InputRestriction.text,
    controller: name,
    fontSize: responsive.screenWidth / 30,
    hint: "İsim",
    textFieldBackgroundColor:
        AppColors.RegisterPageTextFieldColor,
    contentPaddingLeft: responsive.screenWidth / 32.72,
    suffix: RichText(
      softWrap: true,
      text: TextSpan(
        text: '* ',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: AppColors.darkMagenta,
        ),
        children: [
          TextSpan(
            text: '',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: AppColors.darkMagenta,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  )),
```

Comment: where is this asterisk declared in your code?

Comment: @EdwynZN I edited my question to show how I call the widget.

Comment: its beacuse you're using stack and an aligment with CenterRight

Comment: @EdwynZN if i don't use that, the asterisk appears on the top left of the input box. What should I do in order to position it to the right after the hint text?

Comment: you would need to calculate the width of your helper to put it right next to it with a positioned

Comment: Also notice that because there is no logic to hide it even when you fit it where you want it will display above of what the user type

Comment: @EdwynZN but how is that possible because the text length will change each time i use the widget

Comment: @EdwynZN I want * to be a part of the hint text just in different color

Comment: there are ways (but not really practica) like creating a TextPainter just to check the width after painting but with out actually using it (just to get the width and poisition a few pixels left to it) but I would recommend checkin label widget in InputDecorator, maybe that suits you better without more problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Input(hint: "İsim"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget Input({
  double borderRadius = 16,
  double width = double.infinity,
  double height = 60,
  double left = 0,
  double right = 0,
  double top = 0,
  double bottom = 0,
  String hint = "",
  double fontSize = 16,
  bool prefixIconShow = false,
  bool suffixIconShow = false,
  IconData prefixIconName = Icons.person,
  IconData suffixIconName = Icons.lock,
  TextInputType textInputType = TextInputType.text,
  Color color = Colors.black,
  bool password = false,
  Color containerBackgroundColor = Colors.white,
  Color textFieldBackgroundColor = Colors.white,
  double contentPaddingLeft = 0,
  double contentPaddingRight = 0,
  TextAlign textalign = TextAlign.left,
  RichText? suffix,
  List<String>? autofillHints,
  int maxLines = 1,
  TextOverflow overflow = TextOverflow.clip,
}) {
  return Visibility(
    visible: true,
    child: Container(
      width: width,
      height: height,
      padding:
          EdgeInsets.only(left: left, right: right, top: top, bottom: bottom),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(borderRadius)),
        color: containerBackgroundColor,
      ),
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(borderRadius)),
          color: textFieldBackgroundColor,
        ),
        child: TextField(
          textAlign: textalign,
          obscureText: password,
          cursorColor: color,
          maxLines: maxLines,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: fontSize,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            label: RichText(
              softWrap: true,
              text: TextSpan(
                text: hint,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                children: [
                  TextSpan(
                    text: '* ',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
            border: InputBorder.none,
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
              left: contentPaddingLeft,
              right: contentPaddingRight,
            ),
            suffixIcon: suffixIconShow
                ? Icon(
                    suffixIconName,
                    color: color,
                  )
                : null,
          ),
          autofillHints: autofillHints,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

I used label widget of input decorator as an example, deleted some components I dont ahve like colors but of course you don't need to, so now you have to apply some logic to parse Textspan instead of widgets, or maybe just let them pass a color and a `bool isRequired` (or `enum Required {asterisk, check, exclamation}` ) and you will draw an important check for them

[image]